# Python Tkinter - Scrollable canvas containing expandable widgets

Tags: python, canvas, widget, scroll, tkinter

I'm using Python Tkinter and I want to place a variable number of text box widgets in a frame or canvas. The text boxes are packed vertically down the frame, so the first one is on top, the second one is found below, etc.. I can have all the button, listbox, etc widgets in a "left section" of the GUI, while a "right section" will only contain the text box widgets. I want the text box widgets to horizontally expand when the master window is maximized, but because there's a variable number of these widgets, the "right section" containing the text boxes also needs to be able to vertically scroll to view them all.

Currently, I'm using Canvas.create_window to add my variable number of text boxes to the canvas, and while I can scroll the canvas to view all the text boxes, they do not horizontally expand when I resize the window. I have an alternate GUI that uses a frame for the "right section", which allows the widgets to horizontally expand, but if too many are packed, I cannot scroll the frame to see the additional text boxes because I can't have a scroll bar tied to a frame.

Is there any way around this trade-off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple: bind to the `<Configure>` event of the canvas -- this will cause your callback to be called whenever the canvas widget is resized. You then simply need to get the width of the canvas and use that to iteratively resize all the embedded windows.

Comment: I'm assuming to bind to the <Configure> event of the canvas, I need to simply type: canvas.bind("<Configure>"). And to get the width of the canvas, I can use canvas.cget("width"). I'm not sure about using the width to resize all the embedded text boxes though.

Comment: I've been looking online for some help with this. Is it even possible to change the width of a text box after it's already been created? Or change the width of any widget for that matter? I know I could recreate the object, but I'd rather change the width.

I did figure out how to get the width of the canvas with winfo_width(), but I'm stuck on changing the width of the text boxes. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: Ok, I recreated the text objects whenever the window gets resized and it works now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @dmranck: there is no need to recreate the widgets each time. The canvas widget has a method named `itemconfig` that you can use to change the width of the window.